# Want a SQL Query to know the Oracle RAC Node hit by the Current JDBC Connection

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to use Load Balance where I have 3 RAC nodes in my Oracle 10g Database like db1, db2, db3. I have developed a Java program with JDBC connection. This JDBC connection uses load balance. My problem is that I want to print the RAC node (whether db1 or db2 or db3) which is hit by this JDBC connection. Can anybody provide any SQL Query to know the RAC Node hit by the current JDBC Connection? I want to test that load balance is successfully used when we connecting through JDBC thin. Can anybody suggest any alternative ways to test load balance using JDBC Java program?

Answer (score 3):

```
select instance_name from v$instance
```

Comment: This query provides me the same node to which I log in. For example, if I log in to db1 and run this query, it displays db1. for db2, it's db2. The same happens if I run this query from java program or directly in command line on the unix server.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would test that load balancing is working by doing something like

```
SELECT inst_id, count(*)
  FROM gv$session
 WHERE <<something that identifies your connections>>
 GROUP BY inst_id
```

to get a count of the number of sessions per instance.  The `<<something that identifies your connections>>` could be a predicate on the `MACHINE` column (assuming your connections are coming from one or more app servers), the `PROGRAM` column, the `OSUSER`, the `SCHEMANAME`, or anything else that identifies the sessions you are interested in.

If you really want to get this information separately from your Java application, you could

```
SELECT DISTINCT inst_id
  FROM gv$mystat
```

In either case, you can look up which `inst_id` maps to which server using the `gv$instance` table.

Comment: thanks @Justin Cave  
But I am still far from the answer. Both your queries display all the 3 nodes. To identify the connection I used `OSUSER`.  When I run the java program from the local machine through vpn connection with Unix Server. It displays one more count in one of the node. But if I do the same from the UNIX Server itself. I don't find any change in count before and after running the java program. To get the accurate results, I do not close the connection and use `Thread.sleep(10000)` to keep it running for 10 secs.

Comment: @ramesh - Are you sure that the `OSUSER` is the same when the application is run on your local machine and on the UNIX server?  It seems somewhat unlikely that you would be using the same operating system user in both cases.

Comment: @Justin Cave - No the `OSUSER` is different in Unix Server than my local machine. But my question is if I can find more counts while running from local machine, why can't I get any difference while running on unix server.

Comment: @ramesh - If you are filtering the data so that you are only showing sessions opened by a particular `osuser`, you'll only see sessions opened by that `osuser`.  If you run the application on a different machine with a different `osuser`, your `WHERE` clause would filter out that row.  You would realistically need to pick a filter predicate that would identify all the sessions you are actually interested in.

Comment: @Justin Cave - I am really interested in the rac node hit by my jdbc connection. I want to identify my session started by my java program through jdbc connection. What result I got is:  when I filter using `WHERE osuser='unixuser'`, I found no difference in count before run and during the run. But I noticed the count increased by 1 when I filtered using `WHERE osuser='winuser'`. Hope I could explain myself.

Comment: @ramesh - If you connect to the database, a new session is created.  That session will appear in `gv$session`.  If you are not seeing a new session, either you are not connecting to the database you are running the query against or your filter condition is incorrect.  Are you sure that the application is running as the Unix user you think it is?  Have you looked at the `distinct osuser` values in `gv$session` to see if the application is running as some other user?  Have you tried using the `program` or `machine` columns instead?

Comment: @JustinCave - I tried to print `select inst_id from gv$session where osuser='winuser'` from inside the java program run in Win local machine. It prints few nodes. As the number of connections grow through the loop it prints more number of nodes. During the program run I ran the same query from inside the unix server `sqlplus` command prompt. The result comes little different than what the java program prints.

Comment: @JustinCave - Then I tried to run the program in the unix server and print `select inst_id from gv$session where osuser='unixuser'`. Here the no of rows printed by the program are 3, whereas the number of rows are 6 when query run in server `sqlplus` commandline. It displays 6 records even before the run starts and after the run. I noticed the the sequence of nodes in the output changes during Run.
My point is, if 6 instances are already there before starting the run. and even during the run, how to identify which are the new instances allotted to my session. Please help me out.

Comment: @Justin Cave - `select inst_id from gv$session where osuser='winuser'. Output in local machine: `1 2 2`. During prog run, output in server `sqlplus` commandline: `1`. Java Prog Run in Server `osuser='unixuser'`,output: `1 2 2`. During prog run, output in `sqlplus` commandline: `1 1 3 2 2 2`. I didn't use Load Balance here. Could u plz figure out the differences?& Could u plz let me know if it shows 5 to 6 inst_ids, how to identify which is mine? I have tried with `program` and `machine`, little improvement, but no breakthrough. thanks a lot for your support @Justin